# Why equal c++ code transform to different asm code?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, optimization, assembly

Visual c++, debug mode.

```
if(k>=0)

011D14CE  cmp         dword ptr [k],0  
011D14D2  jl          bez+28h (11D14D8h)  

return true;

011D14D4  mov         al,1  
011D14D6  jmp         bez+33h (11D14E3h)  

return false;
011D14D8  xor         al,al  
011D14DA  jmp         bez+33h (11D14E3h)
```

And equal code:

```
return (k>=0)?(true):(false);
011D14DC  cmp         dword ptr [k],0  
011D14E0  setge       al
```

What is faster?
What is faster when Im using second construction in function call?

```
if(i>0)
    Foo(true);
else
    Foo(false);
```

Or:

```
Foo((i>0)?(true):(false))
```

?

Comment: If you're compiling in debug mode, then the compiler won't be making optimizations, so it's a somewhat pointless comparison...

Comment: In theory, there should be no differences, since the compiler has to optimize that anyway. In practice, it depends on the compiler.

Comment: Who told you that both codes are equal, especially in Debug configuration, where `/Od` (no optimisation) is applied.

Comment: does `(k>=0)?(true):(false)` even make sence, why not simply use `k>=0`

Comment: @Vprimachenko no sence, this code for example.

Answer (score 10):

That code is not equal when compiled in debug mode. In the first version you may set a breakpoint on the `return true` branch. This cannot be done with `setge al`.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the code you are looking at is built with a debug switch setting.

The compiler creates code for each line of source so that debugging and source track, more or less.

One instance has 4 lines of code. One instance has one line of code. The compiler outputs code accordingly.

However, you are not going into production with debug code. You will be building the code using optimization.

If you compile both instances using optimization, I will see exactly the same code.